# Copy SQL Server CE .sdf file

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have umbraco with SQL Server CE 4 as database. And it is running on unoeuro hosting. When I trying to copy the whole project to my local directory with ftp client all files are copied except the `.sdf` database file.

Could you please suggest or explain why?

Answer (score 2):

This is the old post but for all the future readers here is a simple workaround:

Create a new file on the root of the website called `app_offline.htm` - that will kill the site. Next download the sdf file using FTP, delete `app_offline.htm` to start the website again and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, select your database and open it's properties.
There should be a field called "Copy to output directory". Set that to "Copy always".

It should now be in your bin folder

Answer (score 0):

The .sdf file is locked by the website connections to the Database file. ive found the simplest workaround is to create a copy of the .sdf file, download it, then rena